# Как указать имя таблицы модели в конструкторе запросов?

Tags: yii2

```
$model = Account::find()
        ->select([
            'campaign_id', //Как тут указать имя таблицы указанной у модели Campaign?
            'name',
        ])
        ->innerJoinWith(['campaign'])
        ->where(['account_id' => $accountID])
        ->asArray()
        ->all();
```

Релейшен выглядит так

```
/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getCampaign() {
    return $this->hasOne(Campaign::className(), ['campaign_id' => 'campaign_id']);
}
```

Если не указывать явно из какой таблицы брать **campaign_id**, то получим ошибку

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column
>   'campaign_id' in field list is ambiguous

Что в принципе логично. Но если указывать явно имя таблицы `campaign.campaign_id`, то появляется зависимость, от которой хотели избавиться использованием модели. (В конкретном случае добавление префикса **tmp_** в имя таблицы **campaign**, чтоб не править все запросы, а только поменять значение **tableName** у модели)

Comment: Сейчас как-то так сделал. `Campaign::tableName() . '.campaign_id'` Но думаю что есть какое-то более правильное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проще всего через alias имхо

```
Account::find()
    ->select([
        'c.campaign_id',
        'a.name',
    ])
    ->from(Account::tableName() . ' a')  
        ->innerJoinWith(['campaign c'])
    ->where(['account_id' => $accountID])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```